# Unable to find scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so, the problem is that I did something, not quite sure what and got a new scene called Untitled in my project and I can't seem to find it in order to delete it. Searched in the build all the scenes there, it wasn't there. Searched in the most logial folders in my assets still didn't find it. The funny thing is that when I click play it works but still can't find it in the build with the other scenes. How can I find this scene file and remove it from my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the solution might be just to open another scene(which means that you just created a new scene and have forgotten to save it and that's why it runs but meanwhile not being seen in the build menu). The second solution if you really have saved the scene and have too many folders to go through in order to find out where you have saved it, just click save as and it might point at the location that you have saved it at.